# Trouble using Redux-Sauce in App? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am supposed to fetch data from an endpoint and display the results using Redux-Sauce.
All is fine except I can't seem to update the state after I fetch data. Read the docs so this is what I could come up with. Please tell me what I am doing wrong!?
How do I update the state calling the action creators inside HomeContainer.js?

Link to codeSandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-sky-56yhi?file=/src/index.js

HomeContainer.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Creators from "../redux/Reducers/reducers";

const HomeContainer = ({ iTunesData, actions }) => {
  const { loading, data, error } = iTunesData;
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const getData = async () => {
      actions.fetchDataRequest();

      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(
          `https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=${searchTerm}`
        );

        // console.log(data);

        actions.fetchDataSuccess(data);
      } catch (error) {
        actions.fetchDataFail(error);
      }
    };

    getData();
    // console.log("On submit handler clicked!");
  };

  // console.log(iTunesData, actions);
  // console.log(searchTerm);
  // console.log(iTunesData);
  console.log(loading, data, error);
  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <h1> Home Container</h1>

      <input
        placeholder="Search..."
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button>Go</button>
    </form>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    iTunesData: state
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    actions: Creators
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeContainer);
```

reducer.js

```
import { createReducer, createActions } from "reduxsauce";

const { Types, Creators } = createActions({
  fetchDataRequest: null,
  fetchDataSuccess: ["payload"],
  fetchDataFail: ["error"]
});

export default Creators;

const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  data: [],
  error: false
};

export const fetchDataRequest = (state = initialState, action) => {
  return { ...state, loading: true, data: [], error: false };
};

export const fetchDataSuccess = (state = initialState, action) => {
  return { ...state, data: action.payload, error: false };
};

export const fetchDataFail = (state = initialState, action) => {
  return { ...state, data: null, error: action.error };
};

// map our action types to our reducer functions
export const HANDLERS = {
  [Types.FETCH_DATA_REQUEST]: fetchDataRequest,
  [Types.FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS]: fetchDataSuccess,
  [Types.FETCH_DATA_FAIL]: fetchDataFail
};

export const reducer = createReducer(initialState, HANDLERS);
```

store.js

```
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose, createStore } from "redux";
import { reducer } from "./Reducers/reducers";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

export default store;
```

index.js

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./redux/store";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

Comment: While it does not answer your question, please note that if you are just learning Redux, all that Redux-Sauce does (and a lot more) is already part of the official Redux Toolkit, which is the way we are officially recommending to write any Redux code nowadays (for 2 years at this point). Please see the official Redux Tutorial for that: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

Comment: actually, this is for an internship and they want me to include redux sauce in the app :(

Answer (score 1):

Your `mapDispatchToProps` is wrong. Written like you want to use it, it would need to acutally bind `dispatch` to the actions, which you don't.

If you want to use that nested, you will have to call `bindActionCreators` manually.

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(Creators, dispatch)
  };
};
```

Otherwise you could also use the "object notation"

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = Creators
```

in which case the bound action creators will be available as `props.fetchDataSuccess`, not `props.actions.fetchDataSuccess`.

Generally, it is also recommended to not use `connect` at all with function components, but the React-Redux hooks `useSelector` and `useDispatch`.

See https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks

Also, as for your internship, please forward the official Redux Style Guide to your team, with best regards from a Redux Maintainer ;)
https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/
We really want them to use the official Redux Toolkit, as it will simplify their code a lot more than Redux-Sauce already does - including allowing for immutable logic in reducers thanks to `immer` integration and containing a full blown api cache abstraction.

Maybe trying that out and prototyping using it might make for a nice internship project for you in the end ;)